# How to do correlation on dynamic parameter that are occuring in request and not in response in JMETER?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am developing a mobile script using jMeter. i.e trying to record and replay mobile web applications using JMeter 2.9 and firefox 43.0.4

I am able to record the application. But it throws an error during replay, as some dynamic parameter is passed with the post data as below:

POST data:

```
skin=&skinLoaderChecksum=&isAjaxRequest=true&**x=****0.7379947959390617**
```

When I checked the same flow in Load Runner, the same failure occurs on the same URL again.

**In Load Runner:**

> HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) and {"errorCode":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","errorMsg":"FWLSE0009W: User identity is null. Check your application''s authentication requirements. These settings must match to the deployed application [project mobile]"}

**In JMeter:**

> Response headers:HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in Sampler Result and in response data: /*-secure- {"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"geqcaecehouktkfn0rfqmmdu6"}}}*/

Is anyone able to help with this?

Responses will be highly appreciated :-).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Worklight server to play with now hence I can provide you only generic information. You need to properly simulate mobile application authentication flow, actually this dynamic parameter can be fetched from the previous response.

Reference links:

- [How to do Worklight Server performance testing](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/how_to_do_worklight_server_performance_testing?lang=en)
- [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)